# show only pdf files while uploading razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor, file-upload

I've been trying to show only pdf files while we browse for upload in a modal box. However, I can see all the files in a box,moreover in a dropdown I can't see filter for specific file types. How can I solve this issue in a dot net mvc application. I've not created any model for this controller, is there any way to handle without model? I've handled the case in controller, but it'd be good if we can filter it right in the view.

Comment: add the `accept=".pdf"` - but that only filters the files displayed in the dialog - a use can still clear it and select any file type they want. You should have a model and bind to a `HttpPostedFileBase` property so that you can add client and server side validation

Comment: This worked. Thanks.